# How do you explicitly destroy a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my angular app, I have a directive. If I remove this one with DOM Manipulation (e.g. jQuery empty()), destroy event isn't called:

```
myApp.directive('joe', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {            
            element.html("Hi !");

            element.bind('$destroy', function() 
            {
                console.log("Bye");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymx4N/

Furthermore, if I remove & add a lot of times this directive with empty() & appendTo() , the number of nodes *always* increase. This means that all directives are always in memory, and the garbage collector never remove these nodes.

Maybe this is a "normal" behavior, because AngularJS can't know when I remove/change DOM nodes directly. However, is it possible to destroy explicitly a directive ? How could I add and remove directives by DOM manipulation, without this kind of """memory leak""" ?

Thanks !

Comment: Angular has ng-if built in, I'm not sure if this will work with your scenario.  But ng-if, unline ng-hide/ng-show, will completely remove the element from DOM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it necessary to include a destroy method in my directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934575/is-it-necessary-to-include-a-destroy-method-in-my-directive)

Comment: I'm used to the $destroy being on the scope, which should fire when the element is removed form the DOM.
 `scope.$on('$destroy', function() {});`  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for though.